# How to add Where clause in the following statement?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do I add a where clause in the following query using the CI? E.g. WHERE name = 'Joe'

```
<?php
    include 'dbclass.php';
    $db = new DB();
    $users = $db->getRows('users',array('order_by'=>'id DESC'));
    if(!empty($users)): 
        $count = 0; 
        foreach($users as $user): 
            $count++;
?>
```

dbclass.php
snippet:

```
public function getRows($table,$conditions = array()){
    $sql = 'SELECT ';
    $sql .= array_key_exists("select",$conditions)?$conditions['select']:'*';
    $sql .= ' FROM '.$table;
    if(array_key_exists("where",$conditions)){
        $sql .= ' WHERE ';
        $i = 0;
        foreach($conditions['where'] as $key => $value){
            $pre = ($i > 0)?' AND ':'';
            $sql .= $pre.$key." = '".$value."'";
            $i++;
        }
    }

    if(array_key_exists("order_by",$conditions)){
        $sql .= ' ORDER BY '.$conditions['order_by'];
    }

    if(array_key_exists("start",$conditions) && array_key_exists("limit",$conditions)){
        $sql .= ' LIMIT '.$conditions['start'].','.$conditions['limit'];
    }elseif(!array_key_exists("start",$conditions) && array_key_exists("limit",$conditions)){
        $sql .= ' LIMIT '.$conditions['limit'];
    }

    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
```

I want help in passing the Where clause condition.
I am using Codeignitor 4.

Comment: the post you tagged does not answer my question

Comment: WHat version of CI

Comment: This is the code in the dbclass.php: public function getRows($table,$conditions = array()){$sql = 'SELECT ';$sql .= array_key_exists("select",$conditions)?$conditions['select']:'*';$sql .= ' FROM '.$table;
        if(array_key_exists("where",$conditions)){
            $sql .= ' WHERE ';
            $i = 0;
            foreach($conditions['where'] as $key => $value){
                $pre = ($i > 0)?' AND ':'';
                $sql .= $pre.$key." = '".$value."'";
                $i++;
            }
        }

I am new at using CI4. I need help with passing the where clause condition

Comment: Well that would have been REALLY USEFUL as part of the question RIGHT OUT OF THE BOX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where the codeigniter parts are in this, that looks like code you have written, so just add a `where` key to the array you are passing like this

```
$users = $db->getRows('users',array('where' => ["name => 'Joe']",
                                'order_by'=>'id DESC'));
```

Comment: You do realise that if you were to read the Codeigniter manual you could use builtin mechanisms to do all this, that have been tested and proved safe

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. I will definitely look into it. Thank you so much for your help in this regard. I highly appreciate it.